# Express: Post Request handler doesn't stop calling a function

Tags: node.js, http, express, post, slack-api

**My express app *should* call a function once, but it repeatedly calls it an infinite number of times when handling a POST request.** I can't figure out why it's called more than once.

This app works with Slack Events API and receives an event from Slack as a post request when a message is posted to a specific Slack channel. Once the app receives the event, it responds with a 200-status response to alert Slack it received it. Then the app extracts the text property from the request and calls postMessage with the text to post the message to a different channel. Posting the message to a different channel won't kick off another event.

The problem is that postMessage() gets called infinitely until I manually crash the app

Here I setup the app and wait for post requests:

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

// Wait for post requests, then extract it's text
app.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body){
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  } else {
    postMessage(req.body.event.text);     //Should be called once
  }

  // Respond to Slack Event API we received their request
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end();
  });
}

app.listen(config('PORT'), (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`App LIVES on PORT ${config('PORT')}`);
});
```

The body of the request is structured like:

```
body = {
  event: {
    text: "important message"
  }
}
```

The function that keeps getting called. This will post a message to a Slack channel:

```
function postMessage(message){
  var messagePath = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xxx&message=' + message;
  request(messagePath, function(error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log('message sent successfully');
      } else {
          console.log('error == ' + error);
      }
  });
}
```

The postMessage method does get called with the correct text. The problem is that it's called more than once.

I thought Slack's API was possibly sending the same request multiple times but from their documentation they will wait 3 seconds between sending requests. My app will call postMessage() about a hundred times in a second, so I don't think it's being overloaded with requests from Slack

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the code for `postMessage` look like?

Comment: Just added it. Does that really matter though? The problem is that its called more than once

Comment: Asking because what could be happening is that: 1) Slack sends you message. 2) You send a message back to Slack. 3) Slack responds with another message. 3) You respond to the Slack response with another message. 5) Slack responds to your response by sending another response. Etc.

Comment: What exactly is this app supposed to do? Is it supposed to echo posted messages? If so, you might want to write an additional check to make sure you are not echoing yourself.

Comment: What kicks off the Slack event is a post into a channel. In this case I'm the one posting into the channel and only post one message so Slack should only send 1 event to the app (then a duplicate event 3 seconds later if they don't get a 200 response)

Comment: "To avoid an infinite loop, we can check the user_name of the body. All hooks post as “slackbot”, even if the name appears differently in chat. We can use this fact to keep our hook from responding to itself." — https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-slack-bots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your bot, which is listening to posted messages and then responding to those messages, is responding to itself when it posts. This will lead to an infinite loop.

The fix is to write a check to make sure the bot is not responding to itself. Inspect `req.body.event` and see if a username is being sent with each message. Then you can write something like this:

```
app.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body || !req.body.event){
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    } else if (req.body.event.user_name !== '<OUR_USER_NAME>') { // Make sure we are not responding to ourselves
        postMessage(req.body.event.text); // Should be called once
    }

    // Respond to Slack Event API we received their request
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: That solved it! You were right - the bot was posting it's own message over and over. For future reference the bot's user property was undefined whereas any regular user has a string of letters/numbers